# forward https connection: client A -> proxy server B -> client C -> server D

Tags: websocket, https, tcp, proxy, tls1.2

Say client A (in my case, a VM) wants to connect to https server D (say en.wikipedia.org). Client A can only connect to Server B (in my case, the host machine) via (virtual) sockets. Right now, software running on the client machine redirects outgoing TCP requests via a (v)socket to B. B is running a special proxy server which forwards the incoming traffic on the (v)socket to server D. Via a second (v)socket channel, A tells B to which domain to point its proxy. I've got this working so far.

Here's the challenge: now I want B to forward the traffic to a client C. For two reasons: 1) B should not know who D is (or any other part of A's http request), and 2) D should see the IP of C, not that of B.

We can run arbitrary code on A and B, but I want C's logic to run in the browser. I assume B and C will have to connect via a WebSocket. The goal is to have everything encrypted while going through B (C knows A's public key, so A and C could establish an AES secret). Then C should receive the data necessary to initiate A's https/tls handshake with D, and the traffic between A and D is router via B and C. C and B must not know the final TLS secret between A and D.

Any ideas which protocols and tools I could use to make this as easy as possible?

Comment: This appears to be a simplified version of what Tor does. My first question is why would C's code run in a browser? Browser websockets cannot listen for connections like a server, they must make the initial connection. So there must be a real server somewhere for C to connect to in order to receive "proxy" connections from other clients. In Tor parlance C is called an *exit* node.

Comment: A could be running a server, such that C could establish a secure websocket connection to A (proxied via B). Through that Websocket, A could send the http(s) requests it wants to make to C, which are then executed via C's browser API.

Comment: I want C's part to run in a browser for UX reasons. A is a type of enclave spawned by B which can run arbitrary code. C will be a non-technical person requesting e.g. an attestation of data on D's server (behind login credentials) from the enclave. The goal is that D can't tell that it's A establishing the https connection (using C's credentials), rather than C.